# Sending an XML File to the MQ

Tags: ibm-mq, ibm-integration-bus

I'm quite new to IIB and MQ Explorer.

Is it possible to send an XML file to a queue and then reading it and modifying it through IIB without 3rd party programs (like `RfhUtil`)?

In IIB I have a Message flow that consists of MQ Input > Java Compute > MQ Output.

My MQ Explorer has 2 Queues, `INPUT` and `OUTPUT`.

I want to be able to send a file to the MQ Input(connected to 'INPUT' queue) and then modifying it in the Java Compute and lastly sending it to the MQ Output(connected to 'OUTPUT' queue)

I'm asking that because I did not encounter an option to send anything except "Put Test Message" which does not have the option to add a file.

I'm running everything locally because I'm still learning (Local Queues as well, if it matters).

Thanks in advance, if the question is lacking information, please let me know.

Comment: 3rd party applications like RFHUtil, Q or MO71 are just MQ applications that other people have written. If you don't want to use other people's applications you can just write your own application to open and read a file, then MQPUT the data to the queue. It is very simple to do and MQ has language bindings for many different programming languages.

Comment: And there is IBM MQ Managed File Transfer - https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=overview-managed-file-transfer

Comment: @MoragHughson thanks for the info, I wrote my own application :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont see any requirement for the input queue. It sounds as if your real requirement is

- Read an input file using a [FileInput node](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/integration-bus/10.0?topic=nodes-fileinput-node)
- Use JavaCompute to construct the output message tree
- Put the output message to the output queue

Answer (score -1):

Yes definitely one option is to use rfhutil. But you said you do not want to use it.

Other option is to use runmqsc commands. I am not sure how much familiar you are with this.

Comment: How would he use runmqsc to send a file to a queue?  Sending files is not the purpose of or a function of runmqsc.  This question already has an accepted answer.  Unless you have another working option it would be best not to guess in an answer.